# What is the cooldown period in K8s HPA

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

Below is the sample HPA configuration for the scaling pod but there is no time duration mentioned. So wanted to know what is the duration between the next scaling event.

```
containerResource:
  name: cpu
  container: application
  target:
    type: Utilization
    averageUtilization: 60
```

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#default-behavior

Answer (score 1):

By Default the Cool down period is 5 mins

we can configure that

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2


kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler

metadata:

  name: example-deployment

spec:

  scaleTargetRef:

    apiVersion: apps/v1

    kind: Deployment

    name: example-deployment

  minReplicas: 1

  maxReplicas: 10

  behavior:

    scaleDown:

      selectPolicy: Disabled

    scaleUp:

      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 120

      policies:

      - type: Percent

        value: 10

        periodSeconds: 60

      - type: Pods

        value: 4

        periodSeconds: 60

      selectPolicy: Max
```